# How to halt a script at a specific time until it is started again by cron?

Tags: debian, cron, shutdown

I have a Raspberry Pi running OSMC (Debian based).

I have set a cron job to start a script, sync.sh, at midnight.

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin sync.sh
```

I need to stop the script at 7am. Currently I am using:

```
0 7 * * * shutdown -r now
```

Is there a better way? I feel like rebooting is overkill.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can run it with the [`timeout` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout),

```
timeout - run a command with a time limit

Synopsis
timeout [OPTION] NUMBER[SUFFIX] COMMAND [ARG]...
timeout [OPTION]
Description

Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after NUMBER seconds. SUFFIX may be 's' for seconds (the default), 'm' for minutes, 'h' for hours or 'd' for days.
```

PS. If your sync process takes too much time, you might consider a different approach for syncing your data, maybe block replication.

Comment: My internet connection is slow hence why it takes so long to sync. Would you recommended any particular signal?

Comment: @Anthony how do you sync right now?

Comment: http://lftp.tech/

Comment: More specifically: https://gist.github.com/feralhosting/4e7e93a7fecd8f55cb4a

Comment: @Anthony you can try other application like syncthing (https://syncthing.net/) or BTSync (https://www.resilio.com/), which work on the block level of the file to sync

Answer (score 9):

If your sync can easily continue after 17 hours of hibernation, try

```
0 0 * * * killall -CONT -g sync.sh || /usr/local/bin/sync.sh
7 0 * * * killall -STOP -g sync.sh
```

If your sync prefers to restart from the beginning, try

```
0 0 * * * exec /usr/local/bin/sync.sh
7 0 * * * killall -TERM -g sync.sh
```

If your sync or its subtasks ignore signals but leave no debris, make that

```
0 0 * * * exec /usr/local/bin/sync.sh
7 0 * * * killall -KILL -g sync.sh
```

`killall` ∈ [psmisc](http://packages.debian.org/psmisc)

Comment: I am using the script found below, with mirror -c it doesn't seem to mind being restarted. Which of the above would you recommend?: https://gist.github.com/feralhosting/4e7e93a7fecd8f55cb4a

Comment: Seeing that LFTP script wanting a SIGTERM to clean its lockfile and considering the likelihood of server timeouts on 17 idle hours or even worse inet[64] renumberings, I would go for `0 0 * * * timeout 7h /usr/local/bin/sync.sh` or my mostly equivalent `killall -TERM` variant.

Answer (score 4):

I would also use cron to "stop" or "kill" that service or script at a specified time.
First create your cron job to run your job or script.
(you can easily run another cron that will kill a job that has a name 
`sudo pkill wget` )

Secondly, you want to see running crontab tasks, in a useful and readable format, in the output of:

```
   ps -o pid,sess,cmd afx | egrep "( |/)cron( -f)?$"
```

They will appear in the first lines, something like this:

```
1108  1108 cron
4288  1108 \_ CRON
4289  4289     \_ /bin/sh -c /path/to/my/crontab/script1.sh
4290  4289         \_ /bin/bash /path/to/my/crontab/script1.sh
4295  4289             \_ /usr/bin/wget LINK
```

First column is PID, second is Session ID and third is the command started by cron. You can kill all the processes related to a specific cron task using the Session ID, so in the example above you should kill Session ID 4289:

```
   pkill -s 4289
```

You need to put the pkill in a script and run this as a cron

Comment: Will the Session ID change each time the cron job runs? What about after powering off and on?

Comment: yes it will change.  But if you script it, you can get the PID and place it into a variable. You may be able to just use the name if it shows up.                            pkill sync.sh